# Can stolen items be used to complete fetch quests?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

For the side quest "Building Bridges" in Gorhart you are tasked with fetching a Greater Healing Potion and returning it to Aery the Fae. I stole the potion from the alchemy shop. I was caught stealing and the potion is now designated as stolen. When I speak to Aery the Fae, there is no option to complete the quest.

So, can stolen items be used to complete fetch-type quests (or any quests for that matter)?

Comment: For a second I thought this question was about Eve Online - in which case the answer would be yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that once you pick up an item it becomes yours. The only issue is if someone spots you picking up an owned item; that's when the trouble starts.

So **yes**, you can steal the potion and use it for the quest.

Comment: Lesson to be learned: Stealing gets you ahead in life, as long as you don't get caught :P

Comment: @Elpezmuerto That's one of the first lessons you learn in RPGs. If it's not nailed down, its yours for the taking (although there may be a pesky homeowner/guard to take out first).

Comment: @CyberSkull...not all RPGs are like that. I was disappointed that Kingdoms didn't make that clear.

Comment: @Elpezmuerto As I understand it, there is a whole thieving tutorial/quest thing later in the game with the Travelers faction.

Comment: @cyberskull With later in the game you mean at lvl 5 right ? right ?

Answer (score 4):

You definitely can complete quests with stolen items. In the "Building Bridges" quest you don't take the Greater Healing Potion to Aery the Fea to complete it. You take it to the warden on the second floor of the inn where he took the injured Fea.